# Use XSLT to arrange a list of items in a table

Tags: xml, xslt, xmltable

I have a linear list of items which I wish to arrange in a table using XSLT. I wish to specify the number of columns as a parameter. For example, if I have a list of 12 items, I can select a 2x6, 3x4, 4x3 or 6x2 table. I cannot see a general way to do this.

I have seen this article: http://www.nedcomp.nl/support/origdocs/xml4/extracted/xpath_hdi_1_4llx.aspx

It tells you how to generate a table with a specific number of columns, but does not allow a general case. (Ideally there would be a loop for the xsl:value-of lines).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355952/xslt-rendering-a-node-sequence-as-m-x-n-table

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, in earlier answers of mine I show ways to do it.

- [[XSLT]: Rendering a node sequence as M x N table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355952/xslt-rendering-a-node-sequence-as-m-x-n-table)
- [How to CSS a two column list of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974313/how-to-css-a-two-column-list-of-items/976798#976798)
- [xslt: How could I use xslt to create a table with multiple columns and rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768665/xslt-how-could-i-use-xslt-to-create-a-table-with-multiple-columns-and-rows/768909#768909)

To give an answer that fits your needs better, you'd have do show your XML.

Comment: @Mark: Glad to hear! :-) (P.S.: Please mark the answer as accepted, if your problem is solved and have no further questions. Thank you.)