# How to style a list to show up as two col in html

Tags: html, css

I have a list as follow:

```
<ul>
   <li>1<li>
   <li>2<li>
   <li>3<li>
   <li>4<li>
   <li>5<li>
   <li>6<li>
   <li>7<li>
   <li>8<li>
   <li>9<li>
 </ul>
```

they appear on output as :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

how can I style them to show up as:

```
1      2
3      4
5      6
7      8
9
```

I need a solution which works on IE and I am happy to use JQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to CSS a two column list of items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974313/how-to-css-a-two-column-list-of-items)

Comment: Try this link http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be to give each list item a defined width, and then give the whole list a defined width equal to two list items. Then float all list items to the left.

CSS:

```css
li{
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    width: 4em;
    float: left;
}
ul{
    padding:0; margin: 0;
    width: 8em;
}​
```

**Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrtzV/)**